# Me.com-like "shaking" textboxes?

Tags: javascript, jquery

On Me.com, (I assume) there's a script that shakes the username and password textbox if you enter your password incorrectly. How would I emulate this effect in Javascript? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`jQuery` UI has this effect in its Effects library:

http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Effects/Shake

Answer (score 3):

I'm on a google TV at the moment, so I can't see the exact code behind that. But you can do that type of behavior with jquery extended by jquery UI using .effect('bounce'); on an element.